# Remove www as well as add https to a domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking to do the following rewrites:

```
http://website.com        >  https://website.com
www.website.com           >  https://website.com
https://www.website.com   >  https://website.com
```

Basically remove www of every combo and redirect everything to https.

Below is the current .htaccess config which seems to solve the first and second one above *kind of* well but falls apart on the 3rd one. Unable to see what's missing here.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# remove www if it has it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R,QSA]

# send everything to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can be done in a single rule itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove www if it has it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: this causes a redirect loop which breaks the site. It also doesn't appear to remove the www when someone visits `https://www.website.com`. Any ideas?

Comment: I also updated my example to show the htaccess includes a WordPress rewrite if that may be causing the loop.

Comment: Rules are correct. First you need to make sure that home url and site url in WP permalink settings is using `https` without `www` otherwise redirect loop will occur. I have also provided your full .htaccess. Make sure you copy code as shown in my answer.